# Entity SQL Sum on Home Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two models like this:

```
[Table("Registers")]
public class Register
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public int countryID{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirmed people")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public int confirmed_people{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public DateTime date{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("countryID")]
    public Country Country{ get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
[Table("Countries")]
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
// GET: Home
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var applicationDbContext = _context.Register.Include(r => r.Country);

        return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

**The question is: How can I sum the confirmed people grouped by country? Example:**

From:

Country  -------  Confirmed

- Paraguay ------- 10
- Paraguay ------- 5
- Paraguay ------- 6
- Paraguay ------- 4

To:

Country  -------  Confirmed

- Paraguay ------- 25

Registrations take place daily, so always a new update country/confirmed

Answer (score 1):

This is with Entity Framework Core 3.1

```
context.Registers.GroupBy(x => x.Country.Name).Select(x => new {
    Country = x.Key,
    Confirmed = x.Sum(y => y.ConfirmedPeople)
}).ToList();
```

More information on GroupBy can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby).

I've renamed some of your properties. See [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#capitalization-rules-for-identifiers).

Full example for testing purposes:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var c1 = new Country { Name = "Paraguay" };
                var c2 = new Country { Name = "Peru" };
                var c3 = new Country { Name = "Chile" };

                context.Countries.AddRange(new[] { c1, c2, c3 });

                context.Registers.AddRange(new[]{
                    new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 25, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-34), Country = c1},
                    new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 5, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14), Country = c2},
                    new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 15, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-12), Country = c3},
                    new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 3, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5), Country = c1}});

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var results = context.Registers.GroupBy(x => x.Country.Name).Select(x => new {
                    Name = x.Key,
                    Count = x.Sum(y => y.ConfirmedPeople)
                }).ToList();

                foreach (var r in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(r);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Register> Registers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        public Context() { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseSqlite("Data Source=registers.db");
            base.OnConfiguring(builder);
        }
    }

    public class Register
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ConfirmedPeople { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `groupBy` like this:

```
        var country1 = new Country {Id=1, Name = "The Us" };
        var country2 = new Country {Id=2, Name = "Iran" };
        var country3 = new Country {Id=3, Name = "Turkey" };

        List<Register> registers = new List<Register>();
        registers.AddRange(new[]{
                new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 5, Country = country1},
                new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 4, Country = country3},
                new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 3, Country = country2},
                new Register{ConfirmedPeople = 2, Country = country1}});

      var result=  registers.GroupBy(x => x.Country.Name).Select(x => new {
            Name = x.Key,
            Count = x.Sum(y => y.ConfirmedPeople)
        }).ToList();
```